# Record Rules for many2one field in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8, record-rules

I have one field called **assessment_group_id** which is many2one field.
The object for the **assessment_group_id** is **assessment.group**

In the **assessment.group** object, there is one2many field called **group_lines**. The object for **group_lines** is **group.lines**.

In this line item, there is many2one field of **hr.employee** named **therapist_id**.

I will book an appointment with the group name.

In the menu called **Today's Appointment**, The user belongs to that group only has to see the record.

In short, I have to write a record rules for many2one field, where user names are in one2many values.

In above screenshot, Assessment Group is many2one field.

In this there is one2many field where the employee names are written.

The user have to see only their appointments. If the appointment is fixed with the specific group and the user has to see only their appointment records.

Any help!

Will something like this gives result

```
[('user.id','=',[ each.therapist_id.user_id.id for val in assessment_group_id for each in val.group_lines])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[('assessment_group_id.group_lines.therapist_id.user_id','in',[user.id])]
```

This rule worked.